# UITableViewDelegate gets called before SIOSocket callback

Tags: ios, delegates, socket.io, chat, messaging

UITableViewDelegate gets called before SIOSocket my callback function is called as follows:

```
            [self.socket on:@"adduser" callback:^(id data)             
            {
                NSArray *dataPieces = [data componentsSeparatedByString: @"~"];
                NSString *pinID = [dataPieces firstObject];
                NSString *pinLocationString = [dataPieces lastObject];


                int i = [dataPieces count];

                for(;[self.pins allKeys] && i!= 1; )
                {
                   [self.UserNames initWithObjects:(NSString*)pinID, nil];

                }

            }
```

My table is using UserNames NSArray but it remains blank since the above callback happens after the TableViewdelegate call..

Comment: You need to call reloadData on your table view at the end of your callback block. However, your for loop doesn't make sense. It's going to be an infinite loop unless i becomes equal to 1, you're using initWithObjects incorrectly, and you wouldn't want to create a new array every time through the loop anyway (if you were using initWithObjects correctly).

Comment: I tried calling reloadData at the end of call back but it did not work for me! Regarding the for loop: I have the code below -                 NSArray *dataPieces = [data componentsSeparatedByString: @"~"];
                int i = [dataPieces count];
So, it works.

Comment: You shouldn't use `initWithObjects` anywhere other than immediately after alloc.  I would use `arrayWithObjects` instead.

Comment: So what value does i have? I tried your loop, and if i is anything other than 1, the loop is infinite (assuming that self.pins.allKeys is not null). If it is one, the loop never runs at all. I can't understand what your intent is. What do you want UserNames to contain? pinID is a single string, so even if your syntax were correct, you would only ever have one object in your array.

Comment: It worked for me after I introduced the following code at appropriate places:                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData];  NSLog(@"reloading");});
[self.UserNames addObject:pinID];   rdelmar, it works for me since i have a && statement. I get array of usernames and I want to add them to the list. Since i'm decrementing i methodically after every name copy statement, for loop will go on until i = 1. There is no question of i taking a value < 1.